# Inserting links into a WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm looking to create some hyperlinks in a Webgrid. I'd like to have the "User Name" column display it's values as hyperlinks instead of text. Is it possible to incorporate the @Html.ActionLink function into the WebGrid below?

The columnName expects a string which corresponds to a property of the model that is being passed to the view. So the problem is how to get that into a link.

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<CIMsWebApp.Client.Group.Entities.IUser>

@{  var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canSort: true, canPage: true, defaultSort: "UserName", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myUserGrid"); }

 @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "dataGrid", 
    headerStyle: "header",
    alternatingRowStyle: "evenRow",
    columns: grid.Columns
    (
        grid.Column(header: "User Name", columnName: "UserName", canSort: false),
        grid.Column(header: "Role(s)", columnName: "Rolebuilder", canSort: false),
        grid.Column(header: "Active", columnName: "ActiveInd", canSort: false),
        grid.Column(header: "Action", format:
                                    @<span><input type="button" class="edit-user" id="@item.PersonId" value="EDIT" />
                                    </span>, canSort: false)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the problem is how to get that into a link.

You could use the `format` parameter to provide any custom format you like for this cell (btw you already did this for the last column):

```
grid.Column(
    header: "Subject", 
    columnName: "UserName", 
    format: item => Html.ActionLink((string)item.UserName, "SomeAction", new { id = (int)item.PersonId  })
)
```